# Convert type family instances to Int

Tags: haskell, type-families

I have this code:

```
type family Id obj :: *
type instance Id Box = Int
```

And I want to make it so I can always get an Int from the Id type family. I recognize that a conversion will be required.

I thought maybe creating a class would work:

```
class IdToInt a where
  idToInt :: Id a -> Int

instance IdToInt Box where
  idToInt s = s
```

And that actually compiles. But when I try to use it:

```
testFunc :: Id a -> Int
testFunc x = idToInt x
```

I get error:

```
src/Snowfall/Spatial.hs:29:22:
Couldn't match type `Id a0' with `Id a'
NB: `Id' is a type function, and may not be injective
In the first argument of `idToInt', namely `x'
In the expression: idToInt x
In an equation for `testFunc': testFunc x = idToInt x
```

So, how can I create a conversion for a type family Id to get an Int?

Based on the answer by ehird, I tried the following but it doesn't work either:

```
class IdStuff a where
  type Id a :: *
  idToInt :: Id a -> Int

instance IdStuff Box where
  type Id Box = Int
  idToInt s = s

testFunc :: (IdStuff a) => Id a -> Int
testFunc x = idToInt x
```

It gives error:

```
src/Snowfall/Spatial.hs:45:22:
Could not deduce (Id a0 ~ Id a)
from the context (IdStuff a)
  bound by the type signature for
             testFunc :: IdStuff a => Id a -> Int
  at src/Snowfall/Spatial.hs:45:1-22
NB: `Id' is a type function, and may not be injective
In the first argument of `idToInt', namely `x'
In the expression: idToInt x
In an equation for `testFunc': testFunc x = idToInt x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that the compiler can't figure out which `a` to use.  Data families are one solution, but an alternative that's sometimes easier to work with is to use a type witness.

Change your class to

```
class IdToInt a where
  idToInt :: a -> Id a -> Int

instance IdToInt Box where
  idToInt _ s = s

-- if you use this a lot, it's sometimes useful to create type witnesses to use
box = undefined :: Box

-- you can use it like
idToInt box someId

-- or
idToInt someBox (getId someBox)
```

The question you need to answer is, for any given `Id`, is there only one type `a` it should appear with?  That is, is there a one to one correspondence between `a`s and `Id a`s?  If so, data families are the correct approach.  If not, you may prefer a witness.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You'll need `testFunc :: (IdToInt a) => Id a -> Int`. Type families are open, so anyone can declare

```
type instance Id Blah = ()
```

at any time, and offer no conversion function. The best thing to do is to put the type family in the class:

```
class HasId a where
  type Id a
  idToInt :: Id a -> Int

instance IdToInt Box where
  type Id Box = Int
  idToInt s = s
```

You'll still need the context, though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not getting it. I posted my result based on your answer in the question so that it would format it properly.

Comment: @taotree: Oh, that's because you're using type synonym families, rather than data type families. This specific problem might actually be a bug, but in general, type synonym families pretty useless; since it's perfectly possible for two instances to have the same associated type, GHC pretty much gives up on deducing anything and you end up with a mess. Using a data type families will solve all that.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a function of type `IdToInt a => Id a -> Int` because there is no way to determine what type `a` is.  The following example demonstrates this.

```
type family Id a :: *
type instance Id () = Int
type instance Id Char = Int

class IdToInt a where idToInt :: Id a -> Int

instance IdToInt () where idToInt x = x + 1
instance IdToInt Char where idToInt x = x - 1

main = print $ idToInt 1
```

Because `Id () = Id Char = Int`, the type of `idToInt` in the above context is `Int -> Int`, which is equal to `Id () -> Int` and `Id Char -> Int`.  Remember that overloaded methods are chosen based on type.  Both class instances define `idToInt` functions that have type `Int -> Int`, so the type checker cannot decide which one to use.

You should use a data family instead of a type family, and declare newtype instances.

```
data family Id a :: *
newtype instance Id () = IdUnit Int
newtype instance Id Char = IdChar Int
```

With a newtype instance, `Id ()` and `Id Char` are both ints, but they have different types.  The type of an `Id` informs the type checker which overloaded function to use.